# Route internet traffic from openvpn tun0 to eth0

Tags: networking, debian, vpn, iptables, openvpn

I can't figure it out. 
How do I give chosen VPN-users access to internet trough eth0? All server traffic goes trough eth1. 
The eth0 is only supposed to give VPN-users internet access on chosen ports and nothing else. 
The users connect trough eth1 and get assigned an IP in tun0 with individual configs, this is one of the users ccd:

> ifconfig-push 192.168.200.5 192.168.200.6 
>   push "redirect-gateway def1"

the user config

> client
>
> dev tun
>
> proto udp
>
> remote 192.168.0.55 1194
>
> resolv-retry infinite
>
> persist-key persist-tun
>
> ca ca.crt cert client.crt key client.key
>
> ns-cert-type server
>
> tls-auth ta.key 1
>
> comp-lzo
>
> verb 3

Server config:

> local 192.168.0.55
>
> port 1194
>
> proto udp
>
> dev tun
>
> ca ca.crt cert
>   server.crt key
>   server.key
>
> dh1024.pem
>
> server 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0
>
> ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
>
> client-to-client
>
> keepalive 10 120
>
> tls-auth ta.key 0
>
> comp-lzo
>
> max-clients 10
>
> persist-key persist-tun

My current IP table rules:

> #Flush all 
>   iptables -F
>  iptables -X
>  iptables -t nat -F
>  iptables -t nat -X
>  iptables -t mangle -F
>  iptables -t mangle -X
>
> #Allow all
>  
>   iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
>  
>   iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
>   iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
>
> #Allow loopback
>  
>   iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
>
> #Block all incoming on eth0 and allow established connections 
>   iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
>  
>   iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

Forwardning turned on:

> sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

After hours on google (https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting) I thought this was the correct way but it doesn't work:

> # Allow traffic initiated from VPN to access "the world"
>       iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 \
>            -s 192.168.200.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

```
# Allow established traffic to pass back and forth
iptables -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED \
     -j ACCEPT
```

```
# Masquerade traffic from VPN to "the world" -- done in the nat table
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 \
      -s 192.168.200.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

## Help is appreciated :)

Network map http://s27.postimg.org/7do7o8ob7/network_map.gif

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set up a policy routing table that tells Linux to use the default gateway behind eth0 for VPN users.

So, you would create a new routing table for packets where source IP address is in 192.168.200.0/24, and make the default gateway for that routing table the default gateway behind eth0.